# Capture Alfresco workflow task re-assignment and display it in workflow summary

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-enterprise

As part of our regulatory requirements, we would like to capture the task reassignment in the workflow history in the workflow summary page.

To achieve this, when the task is getting reassigned, I'm completing current task as system, setting the outcome as Task Reassigned and the task will be assigned to the new person.
This approach works fine for simple review and approve workflow (ie) bpm_assignee (single user).

I couldn't find the correct approach for parallel review workflow types, (ie) if the task the assigned to multiple users (bpm_assignees).

Can you please suggest me, how can I capture the task reassigned for parallel review approval workflow ?

Alfresco Version : 5.0.2.5 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes, I found a way of doing it. I will share the details.

Comment: Hello sorry for disturbing, no rush, i wanted to know if you could share the details of the problem

Comment: I will share the workflow flow today

Answer (score 2):

Here is the workflow structure on how we implemented task reassignment for single reviewer and multiple reviewers.

[image]

Moreover we have created our own workflow pages(start,task-edit,task-details and workflow summary) to render the values. But theoretically it should display the workflow values properly in the OOTB pages.

To support multiple reviewer, you need to use sub-process either with Sequential / parallel. To achieve this you need to configure, *Loop Cardinality, Collection, Element Variable, Sequential and Completion condition* values.

Please let me know, if you need any help on this.

Happy coding

Comment: I sorry to bother again, i just started to study all the workflow stuff so it surely my fault. I build a bpmn based on you pattern, but i need some help with the configuration, here the reference project i made so far https://github.com/p4535992/alfresco-reassign-on-summary

Comment: Is this fixed ? Sorry for delay.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, no I couldn't get it to work, but not for lack of information from you, but for lack of understanding from me.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any help to complete this?

Comment: Thank you for your availability unfortunately the project for which I needed is gone, so I personally don't need it anymore, but if one day I (or anyone else) had to pick it up again, an example working on github would be perfect.